# Read in all shapefiles in a directory in R into memory

Tags: r, for-loop, shapefile

I would like to read all shapefiles in a directory into the global environment However, when I get a list of files in my working directory, the list includes both .shp and .shp.xml files, the latter of which I do not want. My draft code reads both .shp and .shp.xml files. How can I prevent it from doing so?

Draft code follows:

library(maptools)

```
# get all files with the .shp extension from working directory
setwd("N:/Dropbox/_BonesFirst/139_Transit_Metros_Points_Subset_by_R")
shps <- dir(getwd(), "*.shp")
# the assign function will take the string representing shp
# and turn it into a variable which holds the spatial points data 
for (shp in shps) {
  cat("now loading", shp, "...", '\n\r')
  assign(shp, readOGR(shp)) 
                  }
```

EDIT: Problems seems to be in the readShapePoints. Either readOGR (from rgdal) or shapefile (from raster) work better.

Comment: So what is the question? What *"does not work"*?

Comment: Try `list.files(path=".", pattern="shp$", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)`. `recursive=TRUE` will allow locating files that are within subdirectories of the working directory. The pattern `"shp$"` ensures that files listed will _end_ with the letters `shp`.

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have files that end with .shp.xml, so I think the shp$ selects them as well?

Comment: It won't, but that is a good thing, you only want the files that end in .shp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get all the files:

```
# replace with your folder name:
dir <- "c:/files/shpfiles"
ff <- list.files(dir, pattern="\\.shp$", full.names=TRUE)
```

Now read them. Easiest with `raster::shapefile`. Do not use readShapefile (obsolete and incomplete)

```
library(raster)
# first file
shapefile(ff[1])

# all of them into a list
x <- lapply(ff, shapefile)
```

These days, you could use "terra" and do

```
library(terra)
v <- vect( lapply(ff, vect) )
```

Comment: So this creates a list of shapefiles. But I don't know how to use that list.

Comment: I had to some reading on lists, and the syntax for accessing things within lists. The whole list[[5]][1] to access the first column in the fifth element in the list was totally new to me. I was confused by the difference between vectors (character, number, binary) and list (anything you can make a list of, including dataframes, shapefiles, and even other lists.

Comment: if would like them combined, an alternate option using sf and dplyr:               
x <- lapply(ff, read_sf);     
sa <- bind_rows(x)

Answer (score 0):

Going by the Title of your post, I believe you want to list all shape files from your current directory.You may want to use below.

```
list.files(, pattern="*.shp", full.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Then I was unclear. I have a directory of shapefiles, and I wish to read them all into R, using something like readOGR or readShapefile.