# Batch load shapefiles from directory into R

Tags: r, gis, batch-processing, shapefile, rgdal

I was looking to answer some questions, and stumbled upon this:

[Read in all shapefiles in a directory in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764680/read-in-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory-in-r#)

I found the question could have more impact if worded more appropriately.

I think the user meant to inquire on an approach to batch loading shapefiles into R from a specific directory.

I'm providing my solution below. I welcome any that have any recommendations on how to enhance it to do so with their own answers below.

Comment: Wouldn't the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764680/read-in-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory-in-r#) be a better place for you to post your solution instead of opening a new & duplicate post?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I thought about it. However, I thought that it would 'reward' the author of the other post's approach to submitting their question in it's current state (no clarity, no reproducible example, no starter code). I felt that posting my solution there would encourage that person to continue submitting questions in that manner.

Answer (score 3):

```
    #--download shapefiles from here:
    #--https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_cds.html

    wd <- "/My Shapefiles"
    setwd(wd)

    #--store shapefile names as a list
    shp_files <- list.files(wd, pattern = "\\.shp$")

    #--inspect list
    print(shp_files)

    ####################################
    # Batch shapefile loading function #
    ####################################

    rgdal_batch_shp <- function(shp_list) {

      layer_name <- as.character(gsub(".shp","",shp_list))

      shp_spdf <-readOGR(dsn = wd, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, verbose = TRUE, 
                         useC = TRUE, dropNULLGeometries = TRUE, addCommentsToPolygons = TRUE,
                         layer = layer_name, require_geomType = NULL,
                         p4s = NULL, encoding = 'ESRI Shapefile')
    }

    #########################################
    # Pass batch function to shapefile list #
    #########################################

    library(rgdal) #--for readOGR function

    #--Use lapply to pass rgdal_batch_shp function to files list.

    batch_shp_list <- lapply(shp_files, rgdal_batch_shp)

    #--Extract each element in list into its own object

    for (i in seq(batch_shp_list))
      assign(paste("test_shp", i, sep = ""), batch_shp_list[[i]])
```